# Serializing/deserializing a List<> in Xamarin studio (Android Application)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm trying to save some user-generated lists in an Android app.
I wanto serialize to XML and deserialize it afterwards.

But I'm not really sure what to do, 
I am using Xamarin Studio, therefore writing in C#.

What I want to store is this list:

```
    foItems = new List<FoodItem> ();
        foItems.Add (new FoodItem () { FoodItemName = "Kål", FoodItemAmount = 352, FoodItemExpire = DateTime.Now });
        foItems.Add (new FoodItem () { FoodItemName = "Hakket Svinekød", FoodItemAmount = 8030, FoodItemExpire = DateTime.Now });
        foItems.Add (new FoodItem () { FoodItemName = "Peanuts", FoodItemAmount = 520, FoodItemExpire = DateTime.Now });
        foItems.Add (new FoodItem () { FoodItemName = "Molotov Cocktails", FoodItemAmount = 110, FoodItemExpire = DateTime.Now  });
        foItems.Add (new FoodItem () { FoodItemName = "Iceberg Salat", FoodItemAmount = 5400, FoodItemExpire = DateTime.Now });
```

I need a simple serializing/deserializing  example with my list foItems.

Comment: One question at a time, and make it specific please. Your current question is too broad. It could be broken up in (1) how to serialize/deserialize this list to/from a stream. (2) How to save/load a file to/from the user's data folder on android (3) how to build a UI that allows the user to edit a `List<FoodItem>`. For each of these questions, you can find quite some information that is already available on-line and on SO.

Comment: Alright, very sorry. I tend to ramble on when confused. I'll edit as soon as possible.

Comment: You should be able to use [`XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx),  See [Working with the File System](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_the_file_system/).

Comment: @dbc  Regarding the link to xamarins web page, is the code applicable to an Android application? I'm in doubt since it is situated under the IOS section.

Comment: `XmlSerializer` is there -- see [http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/files/](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/files/) and [http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/portable_visual_basic_net/](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/portable_visual_basic_net/).  But I don't know enough about the Android file system to help further.

Comment: @dbc Alright, thanks mate. I'll have a good look.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seriliazing a list in Xamarin - using System.Xml.Serialization

example:

```
        string filepath = "your file pathfile";
        list<your_type> yourlist;
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<your_type>));//initialises the serialiser
        Stream writer = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Create);//initialises the writer

        serializer.Serialize(writer, yourlist);//Writes to the file
        writer.Close ();//Closes the writer
```

Deserializing a list in Xamarin with System.Xml.Serilization

example:

```
        string filepath = "your file pathfile";

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<your_type>));//initialises the serialiser
        Stream reader = new FileStream (filepath, FileMode.Open); //Initialises the reader
        List<your_type> deserializedList; 

        deserializedList = (List<your_type>)serializer.Deserialize (reader); //reads from the xml file and inserts it in this variable
        reader.Close (); //closes the reader

        return deserializedList;
```

Answer (score 0):

For Serializing and Desrializing `List<CustomClass>` object, we can use `BinaryFormatter` in `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary` this would be an easy way. This answer contains simple `List<string>` object, you can modify it according to your Class.

```
void SerializeListObject(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "sample.txt");
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    list.Add("Apple");
    list.Add("Banana");
    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    bf.Serialize(fileStream, list);
    fileStream.Close();
}

void DerializeListObject(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "sample.txt");

    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    List<string> list = (bf.Deserialize(fileStream) as List<string>);
    Debug.WriteLine("1st Item: " + list[0] + "\n2nd Item: " + list[1]);
    fileStream.Close();
}
```